# Identifying different dynamic array VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Sorry for not been enough clear in my previous message!

Here is the situation
A user have the possibility to add new row in an Excel Array.
I would like then to stock the new parameter in the last line of a dynamic array on macro in order to make other calculations.

For example: I have an Array of 2 columns: Parameter and Value
Parameter  <-- B1 column 
Param1
Param2
Param3

Value  <-- C1 column
Val1
Val2
Val3

Hereafter what I have done but it doesn't work!

```
Dim RowCount As Integer
RowNumber = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("C1").End(xlDown).row
'MsgBox "Rows:" & RowNumber-1

Dim tb_val() As Integer
ReDim tb_val(RowNumber - 1)
Dim lc() As Integer

For i = 1 To RowNumber
    lc = PathFinder("Feuil1", Cells(i, 2).Value)
    tb_val(i - 1) = Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(lc(1), lc(2) + 1).Value 
Next i
```

P.S: PathFinder("worksheet1", "word1") send arr(2) with cells details -column & row- of "word1" found in "worksheet1"

```
Function PathFinder(sheet1 As String, word1 As String) As Integer()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim temp(2) As Integer

    Set rng = Sheets(sheet1).Range("A:B")
    Set rngFound = rng.Find(word1, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not found"
    Else:
        temp(1) = rngFound.row
        temp(2) = rngFound.column
    End If
    PathFinder = temp
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: I truly can't say that I understand your question completely, but it seems like you might be able to use Dynamic ranges (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287) and the worksheet_change event to accomplish what it is you're looking to do... Otherwise, please update your question and explain your situation better...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to do this:

```
ReDim Preserve arr(2)
arr(2) = val2
```

The `ReDim` will resize the array. The `Preserve` keeps the values that are already in the array (otherwise they will be re-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand, but here's my opinion :
RowNumber is (i think) wrong ; use 'With' ; the second example shows how to make a very fast array.

```
Dim RowCount As Long 'Long is faster , and you never know how many lines you need
Dim Sh as worksheet
set Sh = thisworkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")

with Sh
    RowNumber = .Range(.rows.count,"C").End(xlUp).Row  ' "C" can be replaced by 3, same effect.
    'MsgBox "Rows:" & RowNumber
end with

Dim tb_val() As Long
ReDim tb_val( 1 to RowNumber)
Dim lc() As Long

For i = 1 To RowNumber
    lc(i) = PathFinder("Feuil1", Cells(i, 2).Value) 'no idea what this does ???
    tb_val(i) = Sh.Cells(lc(1), lc(2) + 1).Value 'must be mistacke, no (i) in lc() ??
Next i
```

Ok, i don't understand all your code, still consider this:

```
Dim MyArray() as Variant 'must be variant for this effect
Redim MyArray (1 to RowNumber , 1 to 3) 'if only 3 columns, Rownumber is the same as above.
with sh 'same Sh as in example above
    MyArray= .Range ( .cells( 1,1 ) , .cells ( rownumber,3 ) ).value 'stocks all the cells (in 3 columns in example in a VBA Array for faster calculs later
    'this way any loop or calculation is way faster, using Myarray(y,x) instead of Sh.cells(y,x).value
end with

'Long Loop + calculs... for i=1 to Rownumber ....

Sh.range( "A1:C" & RowNumber).Value = MyArray 'Writes Back the VBA Array to the Worksheet (only needed if changes made inside the values of the array)

'range ("A1:C" & RowNumber)  has the same effect as Range(cells(1,1) , cells(rownumber,3))    from above , just wanted to say
```